How do I avoid hairlines between flush items when printing from Chrome to PDF?
My web page has a section which looks like this:

When I print it to a PDF from Chrome (which we do in a background service to export the page) it looks like this:

Chrome - or whatever PDF renderer it uses, I suppose - has added white hairlines around the inside and outside of the borders of the HTML elements which make up the section.  It looks rubbish and customers are - rightly - complaining.
Is there a secret meta tag or CSS class, or anything else, which we can change in order to stop it adding these hairlines?  Something like using -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact to get it to print backgrounds?  Is there a -webkit-print-ugly-hairlines: please-no?
I'm not looking for answers along the lines of "use different elements in a different arrangement", because that wouldn't stop the problem in the general case.  I want to stop Chrome from adding these to any page, present or future.

The hairlines appear when you view the file with Adobe Reader or Chrome? Can you post a download link to the PDF file in the screenshot above?

The hairlines appear in Apple Preview.  I haven't tried any other readers, but since the customer is free to choose whatever reader they want, and that's what the users in question use, we can't work around this by using a different reader.  I'm afraid I'm not at liberty to post a PDF sample.
BTW, my question is strictly about Chrome options - about whether there's an existing Chrome option which will disable the ugly lines.

The reason I asked for a sample PDF file (no data, just the 4/5/6 graphics) is to determine whether those hairlines appear in the PDF file or they are a rendering artifact. Most of the time they are rendering artifacts and this is a viewer problem and not a PDF file problem. The rendering problem appears when you have 2 mathematically adjacent rectangles but because their positions are given as float values their edges are rendered on half-pixels leading to what you see as hairlines. Adobe Reader draws rectangles on full pixels and this solves the problem.

Even if they are a rendering artefact, I don't have any choice in which renderer gets used.  My only inputs to this process are to Chrome as HTML & CSS, so I need an HTML/CSS solution that tells Chrome to produce PDFs that won't be rendered this way by in any renderer that the customer might choose.

If they are rendering artifacts then it is a viewer problem and Chrome has no fault here. Unless you redesign the HTML to overlap a bit the adjacent graphics, there isn't much you can do.

I'm not suggesting Chrome is at fault at all!  It has one behaviour, I want a different behaviour, and I'm asking if there's an option to toggle between the two.
